# Is it possible to protect molten magnesium with Butane

Tags: home-experiment

I am currently experimenting with simple methods of metal casting at home. It is conventional wisdom that magnesium is better left to the professionals due to the unfortunate arrangement of its combustion and melting temperatures. I dont have access to any inert gasses or vacuum furnaces; but like a challenge.

The first thing that occurred to me was to use CO2 cylinders you can buy at the supermarket to protect my casting area. Luckily I didnt try that experimentally, since it is a known bad idea. Same applies to water vapor. Molten magnesium will happily steal the oxygen from either, leaving carbon resp. hydrogen gas behind. And a lot of heat of course.

Which brought me to the following counter-intuitive idea: if magnesium cares so little for carbon or hydrogen, could you protect your magnesium from burning with hydrocarbon gas? If I douse my casting mould in butane, then pour my molten magnesium in, I am likely to set the butane ablaze, sure. But I can deal with that; as long as my magnesium stays put.

Is this the dumbest idea ever? Or might it actually work?

To make my question more concrete: what is the known chemistry of magnesium at 700c and pure hydrocarbons? Note that there will also be a lot of silicon dioxide present, which can form a thermite with magnesium, but normally shouldn't under these circumstances. But perhaps the hydrocarbons could catalyze that reaction?

Comment: Molten magnesium requires very special equipment. Do not play around with this.

Comment: It's a dumb idea. If you insist, at least use Argon, cheaply available as welding gas.

Comment: **It is a dumb idea.** // Do not try this using argon gas. Yes argon should blanket the magnesium assuming you have the right equipment which you don't. This isn't a "challenge," rather it is playing Russian roulette.

Comment: You said: "I am likely to set the butane ablaze, sure. But I can deal with that; as long as my magnesium stays put." But, can the others in your apartment store, deal with that, too? Sounds not only dangerous but also careless.

Comment: Thanks for all the folk wisdom so far; still a bit short on arguments based in chemistry though ;)

Comment: For clarity; any experimentation will be done in an open field, well prepared for the worst case scenario of an explosion of burning magnesium

Comment: You're "prepared" for a worse case scenario of an explosion of burning magnesium? How the !@#$%^ are you going to put it out if some gets on you?

Comment: Excuse me, when you say "any experimentation will be done in an open field" I instinctively add "in a dry, woody area". Sorry ;-) . Mixing air with any flammable gas will be critical as you won't have control on the mixing, and explosion will not happen with too low oxygen, or too low inflammables. The pressure wave will be unpredictable, as long a you have not a long experience with bomb laying or other cases of explosions happening.

Comment: Max: I'm thinking of donning a basalt fiber blanket. Not quite 2000c rated but should be good enough for transient splashes.

Comment: Gyro: thinking about it, I think setting the mould on fire before coming in with the crucible would be the better idea, so at least you take out that element of surprise, and I can judiciously place my crucible under the flame front before tipping the magnesium from under it's flux.

Comment: http://www.magnesium.com/w3/data-bank/index.php?mgw=222 Handling molten magnesium.

Comment: Hmm, that source also mentions you shouldn't try putting out a fire with sand; still I don't believe typical melt temperatures suffice to start stealing oxygen from silicon. Then again I really don't have a clue what kind of oxides are in the dirt I am currently working with... Replacing my sand with nacl should solve that though; it has been a fine mould material for zinc so far and I'm sure that won't react with magnesium as it is an integral part of my flux...

Comment: The autoignition temperature for butane is under 700C, so you WILL have a butane fire once the molten magnesium hits the butane saturated mold; flames mean oxygen is present so it is possible the molten magnesium can still react with O2. You can't do this safely in a normal atmosphere, you would need some sort of purge stream over the working area to keep the environment from supporting combustion.

Comment: Ari; thanks, yeah, the way I was envisioning it is to have the casting sit well below the top rim of the casting flask, and have the flamefront rise over that in a way that allows me to stick my crucible under it. I was hoping the natural tendency of butane to evaporate at ambient conditions would be enough to provide a purge stream.

Comment: ...the nice thing is that I can experiment with that without the involvement of any magnesium; or I can try if I can extinguish small lints of burning magnesium by moving it under such a flame front. By controlling the temperature at the bottom of the flask I suppose I should be able to get an arbitrarily strong purging stream.

Comment: answer to: "thinking about it, I think setting the mould on fire before coming in with the crucible ...": I don't know if this is brilliant or crazy, but at least it would circumvent some major hazards and could also contribute some of the heat to keep the magnesium molten. Worth thinking about.

Answer (score -6):

if it might pull the oxygen out of sand , try using magnesium oxide, surely it won't pull the oxygen from its own self. Or using burnt lime, surely it won't pull oxygen away from calcium. 
It might react with butane to form magnesium hydride and carbide ....which would be fun to play with . Also magnesium easily reacts with nitrogen to make the nitride...which is an excellent way to make ammonia

Comment: Not sure those make good mould materials; not without water but that's not a option. Apparently carbides and hydrites don't form in the reaction with co2 or water; are you aware of any particulars of these compounds that might be relevant to the situation?

Comment: This is a *largely* nonsense answer.

Comment: Magnesium most certainly CAN form a carbide when heated with a hydrocarbon! !

Comment: gert is the one full of nonsense

Comment: You'll likely [decompose the hydrocarbon](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1381116907006899).